# Proof for a quadrilateral $ABCD$ inscribed in a circle: $AB\cdot CD + AD\cdot BC = AC\cdot BD$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

This is a follow on from a question I put here: [How to prove $c\sin\theta = a\sin(\theta - B) + b\sin(\theta + A)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3455534/how-to-prove-c-sin-theta-a-sin-theta-b-b-sin-theta-a)

The full question is as follows:$$\\$$
Prove that, for any triangle ABC, with the usual notation and for all values of the angle $\theta$ $$\\c\sin\theta = a\sin(\theta - B) + b\sin(\theta + A)$$

A quadrilateral $ABCD$ is inscribed in a circle. 
By applying the result above to the triangle $ABC$ and taking $\theta$ for the angle $CAD$, prove that: $$AB\cdot CD + AD\cdot BC = AC\cdot BD$$

I have (with help) managed the first part - the proof.  but cannot do the second part.  Also, I don’t understand what $\theta$ is.  Is it C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

With the sine rule, we have for the inscribed triangles ADC and ADB,

$$CD = 2r\sin\theta, \>\>\>\>\>AD = 2r\sin(B-\theta),\>\>\>\>\>BD=2r\sin(\theta+A)$$

where $r$ is the circumradius. Substitute the above into

$$c\sin\theta = a\sin(\theta - B) + b\sin(\theta + A)$$ to obtain

$$c\cdot CD = -a\cdot AD + b\cdot BD$$

which is just,

$$AB\cdot CD + AD\cdot BC = AC\cdot BD$$

Comment: I cannot see how CD = 2r $\sin\theta$ follows from the sine rule i.e. $\frac{a}{sinA} = \frac{b}{sinB}$ etc.

Comment: @SteveHarris - I was referring to the sine rule $\frac a{\sin A}= \frac b{\sin B}=\frac c{\sin C}=2r$. You may see $CD = 2r\sin\theta$ via the right triangle A'DC I just added in the diagram, where $A'C is a diameter.

Comment: @SteveHarris - The circumradius is the radius of the circle that circumscribes a triangle.